# Angular - Why Lazy Load return an empty path?

Tags: angular, angular-lazyloading

I am having an issues with the Lazy Loading. I can navigate between the pages, to paths are correct, but the lazy loaded pages are empty: `http://localhost:4200/contact` and `http://localhost:4200/tours`

The project is super simple, I basically just started.

If you have time have a look at the repository [[Github]](https://github.com/leepaolo/vit)

--- **APP.ROUTES.TS** ----

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

export enum AppRoutes {
  HOME = 'home',
  TOURS = 'tours',
  CONTACT = 'contact'
}

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: AppRoutes.HOME},

 {
    path: AppRoutes.TOURS,
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/tours/tours.module').then((m) => m.ToursModule),
  },
  {
    path: AppRoutes.CONTACT,
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/contact/contact.module').then((m) => m.ContactModule),
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: AppRoutes.HOME,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

--- **NAVBAR.COMPONENT.HTML** ---

```
 <a [routerLink]="'/tours'" routerLinkActive="active">Tours</a>
<a [routerLink]="'/contact'" routerLinkActive="active">Contact</a>
```

Best
P.

Comment: Why not use the command `ng g module tours --module app --route tours`? That gives you everything you need rightaway

Comment: I didn't know. I will use the next time. Thanks for sharing it

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/apps%2Fng-bootstrap-demo%2Fsrc%2Fapp) one example. [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/tree/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app) another

Comment: Btw... when I use the command ng g module tours --module app --route tours --- it give me an error

Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.
Error: Unknown argument: faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems in both `ToursModule` and `ContactModule` you have not imported respective `Routing` modules. You have to import the respective routing modules in the `lazy-loaded modules` as well

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ToursComponent,
    ToursSingleComponent,
    TourDetailsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ToursRoutesModule 
  ]
})
export class ToursModule { }
```

Comment: @PLee Yeah, you have no `RouterModule.forChild` in your `imports`

Comment: I added import { AppRoutingModule } from 'src/app/app.routes'; in contact and tours module.

I didn't get "You have to import the respective routing modules in the lazy-loaded modules as well"

I updated the repository - Have a look if you have time please.

Comment: It works. I imported import { ContactRoutesModule } from './contact.routes';
and
{ ToursRoutesModule } from './tours.routes'; Thanks for the support!